# Classification of technologies used for communication in distributed systems

Tags: reference-request, distributed-systems, communication-protocols, research

I am currently writing a State of Art about technologies used for distributed communication (like CORBA for example). I want to structure the document in way that I don't leave any subset of this technologies out of the research. My proposed solution is to structure the document by Communication Paradigms:

- Interprocess Communication
- Remote Invocation
- Indirect Communication

Am I missing a paradigm? Are there another classifications that could be usefull for structure the document? Also if you can recommend me a good source to read about this topic, I would really apreciate it.

Comment: "I want to structure the document in way that I don't leave any subset of this technologies out of the research." -- That's *probably* infeasible. If the field is not very new and/or inactive, chances are you'll *have* to make informed decisions about what to cover, otherwise you'll have a neverending project on your hands.

Comment: You are essentially asking for the survey of a whole field (which, ironically, seems to be *your* task!) which is too broad for this platform. Community votes, please!

Comment: Im just asking for an alternate way of classification or if I missing one of the Communication Paradigms. I don't know what survey are you talking about. And I know I probably can't write about all the technologies that ever existed, but I can include one of each category at least. This is can be a fairly easy question for a person that has knowledge or experencie with distribute systems. So I am asking for a more informed starting point here, you are not doing  my work. If this question still doesn't comply the rules of the site I can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I decided to classify the distributed system technologies by the communication paradigm that they implement. The categories of communication paradigms I considered are:

- Remote Procedure Call
- Berkeley Sockets
- Message Passing Interface
- Message Oriented Middleware
- Distributed Shared Memory
- Stream Oriented Communication
- Multicast Communication (based in peer-to-peer architecture)

I still have to do some research about some more modern implementations that can eventually use a paradigm not listed here.

Comment: The Berkeley Sockets are for IPC?

Comment: You can use Berkeley Sockets for IPC, but it is not a good idea because they don't provide: distribution transparency, reliability or time decoupling.  They are used  to build higher levels of abstraction. I guess it depends on the application, but in enterprise-level distributed system it is not viable.